# Retrieve zipcodes within Lat Long Coordinates

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have 2 points containing Lattitude and Longitude Coordinates. I'd like to figure out how to find the zipcodes within this set of Points. I have a query which provides me with a set of zipcodes based on a central lattitude and longitude point extending X miles in radius, but that isn't precisely what I am looking for. What I am looking for is to extract the zipcodes within two points.

So, for example:

`Coordinate A = 28.37,-81.5568 (Orlando, Florida)`

`Coordinate B = 25.6132,-80.3474 (Miami, Florida)`

Here is my query to extract all locations from my database based on a central point (In this case I am using Orlando, FL:

```
$sql="SELECT zip_code_id, (
        3959 * ACOS (
            COS ( RADIANS(28.37) )
        * COS( RADIANS( lat ) )
        * COS( RADIANS( lon ) - RADIANS(-81.5568) )
        + SIN ( RADIANS(28.37) )
        * SIN( RADIANS( lat )
       ))) AS distance FROM zip_code HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;";
```

What I am trying to determine is the zipcodes within Orlando to Miami based on these two points.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you want the zipcodes that lie along that line? The formula you have gives all zipcodes in a radius... You could adapt that to find the ones on the line! Can you put in the formula?

Comment: or do you mean the zipcodes bounded by the region between the two lines (ie. a rectangle)?

Comment: @J_mie6 I updated my question. Currently I have a query which provides a list of points based on a certain distance. That is correct. I am seeking the zipcodes bounded by a region. What I am confused about is if there should be 4 points, denoting one for each point in the rectangle?

Comment: no, there need not be 4 points! just the opposite corners will do! Then if you can do something like `find the zipcodes which satisfy: LatB < lat < LatA and LongB < long < LongA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get points between the two coordinates - maybe using the [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula and then collect the zipcodes for the points along the line.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out is how to collect the zipcodes based on using this formula.